# Can a character with the Alchemist feat make Assassin poisons?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, alchemy

Is the assassin poison considered an alchemical item? As I read alchemist(Eberron) it states poison as an alchemical item.

Can someone with the [alchemist](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=652) feat make assassin poisons?

Answer (score 4):

No they cannot.

Only Executioner Assassins with the Poison Use class feature can create assassin poisons. They function as the class's daily power use, and therefore are equivalent in power. Allowing them to be created by a character with the alchemy feat provides entirely too much utility to anyone with alchemy.

Comment: I agreed until I read the DMG. RAI, the Poison Use is suppose to be a Daily but RAW poisons are alchemic items and the DMG has Carron Crawlers Brain Juice as a normal lv. 5 poison.

Comment: Yes, but it's a different poison. Looking at: http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=805, Carrion Crawler Brain Juice costs 0gp, and is "Consumable: Assassin poison" if we contrast this with alchemical poisons, Walking Death has a recipe, a recipe cost, is labeled an alchemical item, and has a rarity. From the core DMG, the brain juice is *not* an item, instead it's "Level 5 Poison." If players wish to purchase *that* version, they can through DM approval. They cannot use alchemy (no recipe) nor can they produce the enhanced assassin version.